# Syntax check on a java file

Tags: java, syntax, grammar

For a given java file, I'd like to check if it's syntactically correct. ie. If it has semi-colons in the right places, matching parenthesis etc. Importantly, I need to check the file in isolation from all of its dependencies.

[This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298856/syntax-checking-in-java) is promising, however it's really doing a semantic check rather than a syntactic check. It does what a compiler would do - check all the imports statements as well as verify external classes that are referenced in the code.

Is there a way to do a true syntax check? (A check that only inspects the raw text against Java's formal grammar)

Comment: Yes we do use an IDE. There's a large list of legacy files that I need to analyse, many without the libraries they depend on

Comment: Try to compile it using javac

Comment: The answer you linked to suggests using Eclipse's JDT parser module, that returns an abstract syntax tree. That should do it, I guess.

Comment: Thanks Jens, javac would do a deeper analysis than I need

Comment: Are you looking for a tool or for some code?

Comment: Hi Margaret, either would be fine

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061548/java-tree-parser-output-for-antlr sounds like a good start.

Comment: In which way doesn't the answer you linked to fit your request?

Comment: Hi Jimmy, it tells me there are errors with the class's dependencies. Which I already know are missing. In other words, it's doing both syntactic and semantic checks, and I just want to do a syntactic check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create or use a Java source code parser. For some parser generators there are public Java grammars available - you could use it to generate the parser.

E.g. [Java 8 grammar](https://github.com/antlr/codebuff/blob/master/grammars/org/antlr/codebuff/Java8.g4) for [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) (no idea about quality of that grammar though, you'd have to do your evaluation - but the grammar is written by the author of ANTLR, so should be OK I guess).

Answer (score 3):

As Jiri suggested, use the ANTLR library to put together a syntax checker.

1. Download and extract the ANTLR grammars from [here](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4)
2. Download the ANTLR4 jar from [here](http://www.antlr.org/)
3. Run the following command to generate classes from the Java 8 grammar:

   > java -jar antlr-4.5.3-complete.jar
   >   ~/Downloads/grammars-v4-master/java8/Java8.g4
4. Copy the .java files that were created into your project

Then you can write your syntax checker:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException, IOException {

    ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRFileStream(args[0]);
    Java8Lexer lexer = new Java8Lexer(input);
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    Java8Parser parser = new Java8Parser(tokens);

    final StringBuilder errorMessages = new StringBuilder();
    parser.addErrorListener(new BaseErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void syntaxError(Recognizer<?, ?> recognizer, Object offendingSymbol, int line, int charPositionInLine, String msg, RecognitionException e) {
            String err = String.format("Failed to parse at line %d:%d due to %s", line, charPositionInLine + 1, msg);
            errorMessages.append(err);
            errorMessages.append(System.lineSeparator());
        }
    });

    parser.compilationUnit();
    int syntaxErrors = parser.getNumberOfSyntaxErrors();

    if (syntaxErrors == 0) {
        System.out.println(args[0] + ": PASS");
    } else {
        System.out.println(args[0] + ": FAILED (" + syntaxErrors + " syntax errors");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was researching how to do a quick java syntax-checker for usage in vim. I inspired by [@Fidel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38697211/2915423)'s answer (thanks for the example checker!) but it didn't suffice me as I needed it to work in a standalone way.

Here is a step by step process of what had to be done in order to have runnable command:

- Run:

```sh
# download and generate .java classes
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/antlr/antlr4/4.5.3/antlr4-4.5.3.jar -O antlr4-4.5.3.jar
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antlr/grammars-v4/master/java8/Java8.g4 -O Java8.g4
java -jar antlr4-4.5.3.jar ./Java8.g4
```

- Then write a syntax checker, perhaps similar to [@Fidel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38697211/2915423)'s one and place it under `package checker;` place it directly under `./checker` directory
- Also place all of the generated `.java` classes under that package (ie. put `package checker;` to the first line of all the files)
- Run:

```sh
# prepare directory structure and compile
mkdir -p checker && mv *.java ./checker/
javac -cp antlr4-4.5.3.jar ./checker/*.java
```

- Prepare a Manifest file that will look similarly to:

```
Class-Path: antlr4-4.5.3.jar
Main-Class: checker.<name-of-your-checker-class>
```

- Run:

```sh
# package into a jar file and run to test everything works
jar cfm checker.jar Manifest.txt checker/*.class
java -jar ./checker.jar <filename-you-want-to-run-syntax-check-against>
```

For my usage in vim I then created a simple shell script to wrap execution of the process of running the java jar that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR=$(readlink -f $0)
DIR=${DIR:0:(-3)}            # put the length of the script name here instead of '3'

java -jar ${DIR}checker.jar $@
```

Then make it executable and symlink it under `$PATH`:

```sh
chmod a+x <file-name>
sudo ln -s /path/to/the/script /usr/bin/java-syntax
```

And finally added a keybinding like this into a `.vimrc` file (ie. to map running the syntax-check when F10 key is pressed):

```vimscript
" java syntax validation                                                        
map <F10> :!java-syntax % <CR>
```

I also stored the process into a [github repository](https://github.com/helvete/java_syntax), where all the commands are prepared in a makefile and it suffices to run `make` in order to build and package the checker. Feel free to use it as an inspiration.